# How to configure Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.CLI like I can configure Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger in startup.cs

Tags: swashbuckle

I need to configure Swashbuckle CLI to generate an Swagger spec in the OpenAPI 2.0 version. I do this in `startup.cs` with the following code:

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder application, IWebHostEnvironment environment)
        {
                application.UseSwagger(c =>
                {
                    c.SerializeAsV2 = true;
                });

                application.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
                {
                    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/edgezones.json", "EdgeZoneRP Swagger");
                });
            }

            ...
        }
```

but `startup.cs` seems to have no effect on Swashbuckle CLI's Swagger generation, as `swagger tofile` generates a Swagger spec in the OpenAPI 3.0 version (the default)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that reading the manual page can help!

Usage: dotnet swagger tofile [options] [startupassembly] [swaggerdoc]

startupassembly:
relative path to the application's startup assembly

swaggerdoc:
name of the swagger doc you want to retrieve, as configured in your startup class

options:

--output:  relative path where the Swagger will be output, defaults to stdout

--host:  a specific host to include in the Swagger output

--basepath:  a specific basePath to include in the Swagger output

**--serializeasv2:  output Swagger in the V2 format rather than V3**

--yaml:  exports swagger in a yaml format